# Ol Extensions for OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

Can I use these libraries in OpenLayers v.4?

I'm specifically using 4.6.5 version and I would like to apply a search bar for example.

http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/search/map.control.search.html

Comment: Have you sent a message to the developers asking about compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [doc](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/) as a tiny reference saying it works with "*ol/ol3/ol4*"

Looking at the source of the sample you have linked, the master version of Open Layers is used (having a tag of v4.6.4-41 at time of writing)